# How do I use Istanbul Code Coverage to cover functions that aren't exported

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, istanbul, redux-thunk

I have some redux-thunk actions/async actions and Istanbul pointed that some no-exported functions aren't covered.

So, I was wondering there's a way to test that?
Also one of my async actions performs all sorts of if statements to make sure that the API is really returning infos, if not it returns an empty array (don't know if it's right, guess not(how should it be done then?))

here's an example screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Whether or not something is exported doesn't matter, just whether it runs. Seems like you need to add tests to test the API?

Comment: If those functions are not covered, that means that either they are dead code that is used nowhere and should be removed or that they are not called during your tests and those should be improved (which actually is the whole point of a coverage tool).

Comment: yeah, but how do I test then, know what I mean? how to access the function to send something and expect the result to be equal something? as I can't call the function itself, I'm kinda lost here :( sorry

Comment: You need to write test code that executes the promise callbacks. Right now, those callbacks are in red, which indicates Istanbul hasn't reached that path, which in turn means your `setActivity` is never invoked.